# Azure CI pipeline - Run docker container for use in subsequent jobs/stages

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, github-actions, gitlab-ci

I am trying to figure out how to build a pipeline that will run a docker container that hosts an API, and then for subsequent jobs/stages that API from the container will be available.

It would be something like the below(in Azure). I want to run StartAPI, and once the Docker image is running and API is available I move to the next stage/job (UseAPI). But at stage StartAPI, the stage would just hang as the docker image is running so would not move to next stage.

```
- stage: StartAPI
  jobs:
  - job: RunDockerAPI
    displayName: Run API Docker Container
    steps:  
    - script:   docker run.....
      displayName: 'Run Docker'

- stage: UseAPI
  jobs:
  - job: UseDockerAPI
    displayName: Use API Docker Container
    steps:  
    - script:   curl http://127.0.0.1
      displayName: 'Run cURL Command'
```

Once my UseAPI stage is complete, I would want to stop the Docker container running.
If someone could point me to a pipeline example in Azure, GitHub, GitLab etc I would appreciate it.

I know how to run each stage individually, but at docker run stage, the stage would just hang and not move to next stage

Comment: What is the exact command for running the docker container? `docker run.....` is not helpful.

Comment: Check out Service containers for [tag:GitHub-Actions]: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-containerized-services/about-service-containers

Comment: Since every job runs on its own runner and is terminated fully when the job completes, your current approach can't work with Github Action, rely on service containers instead, publish your container to GitHub's container registry and then reference it in the next job's service container list.

Comment: Azure Pipelines has a very similar feature: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/service-containers?view=azure-devops

Comment: @jessehouwing The YAML **is** Azure Pipelines. I don't know why this is tagged with [github-actions] at all.

Comment: Me neither, but the question includes guidance for any platform.

Comment: @jessehouwing Thanks a million for the replies, the question was generic but think service containers is something im going to look at